# Using stored procedure parameters in delete queries deletes all records

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.6

Alright, y'all, here's the deal.

I want to create a stored procedure to delete values from certain tables. This is what it looks like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `delete_sap`(sap_to_delete CHAR(45))
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;

    START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT sap_to_delete as ' '; -- Just want to make sure it's coming in. It is.
    DELETE FROM data01 WHERE sapid = sap_to_delete;
    DELETE FROM sap_has_owners WHERE sap_sapid = sap_to_delete COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    DELETE FROM sap_has_reviewers WHERE sap_sapid = sap_to_delete COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    DELETE FROM sap_has_readonly WHERE sap_sapid=sap_to_delete COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    DELETE FROM sap_has_editors WHERE sap_sapid=sap_to_delete COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    DELETE FROM page WHERE sapid=sap_to_delete;
    DELETE FROM element WHERE element.sapid=sap_to_delete;
    IF `_rollback` THEN
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

I realize I could alter some of these tables to `ON DELETE CASCADE` based on foreign keys, but this isn't my database so ...

Anyway, currently, when I call with `CALL delete_sap("idtodelete")`, EVERYTHING is deleted. Or, all content from every table that I only mean to delete certain records from. I receive no warnings. I've mistyped something in some way that makes this delete everything.

Let's say my data01 table is built like so:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `data01`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `data01` (
  `sapid` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `pageid` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `elemid` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `json` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sapid`,`pageid`,`elemid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

and I've put a few things in it:

```
| sapid      | pageid     | elemid     | json  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------        
| 3Fdk...jo8 | HhN...ajn8 | xYh5...uUz | { "os": "Mac", "name": "Safari" }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
| 6moo...Vwm | 0wR...2n47 | Bo3F...1lC | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| 6moo...Vwm | 0wR...2n47 | DRvb...oje | NULL   
| 6moo...Vwm | kYAy...AJq | GhJG...KzA | {"title":"My test sap","preparedBy":"Ghost McFee","date":"2023-09-13T03:23:21.062Z"}
| p4th...fvW | Cokg...Ly4 | thF...CmpT | "What is the goal!"
```

Again, when I use the statement `CALL delete_sap("6moo...Vwm")` I would hope only the records with that sapid are deleted. That's not the case. Everything's gone.

What am I missing? TIA!

Edit to add, when I change to this, nothing is deleted (not even what I expect to go), but no errors.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `delete_sap`(IN sap_to_delete CHAR(45))
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;

    START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT sap_to_delete as ' ';
    DELETE FROM data01 WHERE data01.sapid = sap_to_delete;
    DELETE FROM sap_has_owners WHERE sap_has_owners.sap_sapid = sap_to_delete COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    DELETE FROM sap_has_reviewers WHERE sap_has_reviewers.sap_sapid = sap_to_delete COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    DELETE FROM sap_has_readonly WHERE sap_has_readonly.sap_sapid = sap_to_delete COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    DELETE FROM sap_has_editors WHERE sap_has_editors.sap_sapid = sap_to_delete COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    DELETE FROM page WHERE page.sapid = sap_to_delete;
    DELETE FROM element WHERE element.sapid = sap_to_delete;
    IF `_rollback` THEN
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Based on some questions (and I've made a few changes to try to weed out any bad apples), this is what I can see from `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE delete_sap`:

```
| Procedure  | sql_mode                                                                                  | Create Procedure                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| delete_sap | STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION | CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `delete_sap`(IN sap_to_delete CHAR(45))
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
    
    START TRANSACTION;
    DELETE FROM data01 WHERE data01.sapid LIKE sap_to_delete;
    DELETE from sap WHERE sap.sapid LIKE sap_to_delete;
    DELETE FROM page WHERE page.sapid LIKE sap_to_delete;
    DELETE FROM element WHERE element.sapid LIKE sap_to_delete;
    IF `_rollback` THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
    COMMIT;
    END IF;
END | utf8mb3              | utf8mb3_general_ci   | utf8mb4_general_ci |
```

Does it matter if the collation is `utf8mb3_general_ci`? How do I change it for this procedure definition?

Comment: are you able to see the definition of the proc if you can spot anything obvious by doing SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE delete_sap ?

Comment: Start from the bottom most children of the entity hierarchy and work up.

Comment: @Bohemian I'm not sure what you mean by entity hierarchy. Could you explain?

Comment: @NandalalSeth I added `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE delete_sap` to the bottom. I don't use sql or mariadb very often, so I'm not sure if it's telling of an issue.

Comment: @S.Dale, sorry I do not see any issue with the procedure. Can you do the following to ensure that it is the procedure that is deleting and not some other process .... select count(1) from data01; CALL delete_sap("6moo...Vwm"); select count(1) from data01; –

Comment: @NandalalSeth with the top one, everything is deleted (it's empty). With the bottom query, nothing is deleted.

Comment: @S.Dale, if the first select count(1) from data01 returned no rows, then that would mean that there was no rows in data01 table even before you called delete_sap procedure. Can you give the list of steps you are doing to confirm that the rows were there in the table before you called the delete_sap, and then no rows after ? Also, are there any triggers on any of these tables - select * from INFROMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS;

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, my issue was collation, as I discovered from following @NandalalSeth 's suggestion to check out `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE delete_sap`. Running that query revealed

```
| Procedure  | sql_mode                                                                                  | Create Procedure                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| delete_sap | STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION | CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `delete_sap`(IN sap_to_delete CHAR(45))
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
    
    START TRANSACTION;
    DELETE FROM data01 WHERE data01.sapid LIKE sap_to_delete;
    DELETE from sap WHERE sap.sapid LIKE sap_to_delete;
    DELETE FROM page WHERE page.sapid LIKE sap_to_delete;
    DELETE FROM element WHERE element.sapid LIKE sap_to_delete;
    IF `_rollback` THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
    COMMIT;
    END IF;
END | utf8mb3              | utf8mb3_general_ci   | utf8mb4_general_ci |
```

But that procedure is also EXTREMELY chunky and cumbersome. After updating some foreign keys, I only needed to have one delete statement.

Also, I can simply exit and rollback on a sqlexception, instead of updating a boolean.

Ultimately, my solution is as follows.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `delete_sap`(IN sap_to_delete CHAR(45))
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN
        SHOW ERRORS;
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
    
    START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT sap_to_delete;
    DELETE from sap WHERE sap.sapid LIKE sap_to_delete COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    COMMIT;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Thank you all for providing guiding questions / suggestions that helped me get here.